# Having an icon beside text in a button

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button which is all css. I want to have an icon to the left of the text. How do i do that?

Thanks.

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
button {
    background: orange url(images/icon.png) no-repeat 5px center;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

and another way :

```
button {
    postion: relative;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

button img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}

<button type="submit"><img src="icon.png" /> Submit</button>
```

Comment: you could also just do this: `<button type="submit"><img src="..."> Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using submit input buttons, then give the button some left padding and add the image as a non-repeating background image to the button with CSS.

```
<input type="submit" class="imageBut submitBut" value="My submit button text" />
```

CSS:

```
.imageBut {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-position: 0 0; /* Adjust as appropriate */
    background-repeat: none;
}

.imageBut.submitBut {
    background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something along the lines of

```
input {
    padding-left: 24px;
    background: url(an-icon.png) 4px 50% no-repeat;
}
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmmmm. How about something like:

```
<img src="the-icon"><input type="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery, like this:

```
$("#button-submit").button({icons: {primary:'ui-icon-play'}});
```

With the HTML like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button-submit" /><label for="button-submit">Start</label>
```